# In ruby automation will script wait for 20mins

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Hi am doing automation for web application where I run the  job  after that there are  process steps  I need catch one step. To get that step it takes 6mins. Am using  Time. Now method am getting error undefined method 'minutes' for 6:Fixnum.

Is there anyway to wait the script for few minutes .

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: That's an ActiveSupport method, so you either need to require that library or find an alternative.

Comment: Depending on how this time value needs to be processed you may be able to use `expected_job_time = Time.now + 60*6`

Comment: It worked thank you.